# Why is the 'less' command unable to read data from standard input?

Tags: linux, less, input-method

The command `less < brown_fox.txt` will read the data from `brown_fox.txt` and print it on the screen. But if I want to read data from standard input or keyboard using less command, how should I go about it?

I tried the following commands,

```
less
less <&0
```

but neither of them was successful.

Comment: Note `ls -l | less` works. This shows `less` is able to read data from its standard input. Using `less` at the end of a pipeline is quite common. You probably meant `less` is not eager to read actual data from the terminal.

Comment: Please describe what you want to achieve (what you want `less` to do for you), and it might be easier to help (with or without using `less`).

Answer (score 2):

In order to read from `stdin`, you can use

```
less -
```

However, that is more suitable for cases where you want to pipe the output of another command into `less`. Typing from the keyboard will also work, but you will be typing in the blind and have to press `Ctrl-C` to return control to less, which makes that kind of usage rather difficult (if not pointless). **Note also that this is undocumented and may not be portable at all!**

Maybe you want to specify further why you would like `less` to read from `stdin`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to send commands to `less`, you can do this using `+` at the command line, for example:

```
less +G somefile

ls -l | less +G
```

This is equivalent to `less` opening and you then typing the `G` command at the default prompt.

---

If you're talking about `less` paging information that you have typed, you can use a heredoc, but I'm not sure of the use case for that:

```
less << EOF
hello
world
EOF
```